# sqlite3 foreign key not working at all

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

```
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE users(id integer PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE posts(id integer PRIMARY KEY, body TEXT, user_id int, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id))")
```

I already enabled pragma foreign_keys = on, and it returned a 1. I created this database with python, and I used a database viewing program to check the fields. It showed everything correct from the primary keys, to the text fields, BUT no foreign key. It displays user_id as an int, nothing more. I also don't get any values put into it when making inserts. I feel that if I insert a user, than it should create a row, and be references in posts. But when I query the user_id field, it returns 'none'. What am I doing wrong?

edit:here is how I got it to work

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():       
    c = g.db.execute("INSERT INTO posts(body) VALUES(?)", [request.form['body']])
    b = g.db.execute("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)", [request.form['name']])
    get = g.db.execute("SELECT id from users where username=?", [request.form['name']])
    id = get.fetchone()  
    userid=str(id[0])
    bet = g.db.execute("SELECT id from posts where body=?", [request.form['body']])
    bid = bet.fetchone()
    postid = str(bid[0])
    e = g.db.execute("UPDATE posts SET user_id = (?) where id = (?)  ", [userid,postid])
    g.db.commit()
    flash('subbmited')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Everything in your descriptions sounds correct. Your feelings are wrong. What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to create a table users(name,email,password) and posts (body,userid). I then want to be able to retrieve from the database, a post and who made the post. Than I want to display that in html for easy readability. I think I am doing the table conception correct, but I could be completely wrong. I thought this is how others did it as well. I want the foreign key to auto update when the user table is updated. I tried "on update cascade" but that didn't help.

Comment: Could you show a specific example of an update that should be propagated?

Comment: If I create an entry into the users table, with a username, as well as a body entry into the posts table, I want the user_id in the post table to be autoupdated with the userid who made the post. Or I can insert it myself. I don't have any code to show because I can't get anything to work :(. Check edit I made for a bit of the code

Comment: ok I have found a solution to my own answer, although the code is horrid and i am sure there are a million better ways but I will update my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys are used for managing relationships between records.
However, in your code, you have not told the database that the two inserted records are related in any way.

You should insert the `users` record first so that you can use the newly inserted ID for the `posts` record:

```
def add():
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)", [request.form['name']])
    g.db.execute("INSERT INTO posts(body, user_id) VALUES(?,?)",
                 [request.form['body'], cursor.lastrowid])
    g.db.commit()
    ...
```

(Do you really want to create a new user for each post?)